# Custom class Error Handling in Tornado Application Python?

Tags: tornado

The error raised in the function outside the Handler in tornado application are passed to @gen.coroutine decorated function inside handler, the caught exceptions getting shown in console but not showing in application (say in POSTMAN)

below is the set of custom exceptions declared

```
class ApplicationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, code):
        self.message = message
        self.code = code
        super(Exception, self).__init__(message)

class ServerError(ApplicationError):
    def __init__(self):
        ApplicationError.__init__(self, "Server Connection NOT Established", 500)

class InvalidTenantID(ApplicationError):
    def __init__(self):
        ApplicationError.__init__(self,"Either TenantID or ModelID is incorrect" , 404)

class InvalidPayloadPOSTError(ApplicationError):
    def __init__(self):
        ApplicationError.__init__(self,"Payload Mismatch",400)
```

Now the handler has

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self, model_id):
        try:
            data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
            yield self.predict('mod1')
        except ApplicationError as e:
            self.respond(e.message, e.code)
        except Exception:
            error = ServerError()
            self.respond(error.message, error.code)

    @gen.coroutine
    def predict(self, mod):  
        model = mod(load from database)
        try: 
           values = (load from database)
        except ApplicationError as e:
            logger.warning(e.message, e.code)
        except Exception:
            error = InvalidPayloadPOSTError()
            logger.warning(error.message, error.code) 
        results = yield self._b_run(model, values)
        self.respond(results)

    def respond(self, data, code=200):
        self.set_status(code)     
        self.write(data)
```

Outside handler I have the mod function (called inside the predict in handler)

```
def mod(model):
    try:
        elastic_model = es.get(index = "index_name", doc_type='doc',id = model)
    except ApplicationError as e:
        logger.warning(e.message, e.code)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        logger.info('Either Tenant_id or Model_id NOT Found')
        error = InvalidTenantID()  
        print(error)
        logger.warning(error.message, error.code)
```

Here if the elastic_model in the mod function raise error, the exception of InvalidTenantID is thrown and displayed in the console, but in the application (POSTMAN) the message of ServerError() in the post method is displayed,

Also if the exception occurs in the predict method the message of InvalidPayloadPOSTError() is displayed in console, not in application, there message of ServerError() is displayed.

how should I grab the exceptions of the other functions, I understand that @gen.coroutine decorator is finally resulting out.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not thrown back, so I used raise, it is working,

for the predict function instead of error = InvalidPayloadPOSTError(), use raise  InvalidPayloadPOSTError()

```
    @gen.coroutine
    def predict(self, mod):  
        model = mod(load from database)
        try: 
           values = (load from database)
        except ApplicationError as e:
            logger.warning(e.message, e.code)
        except Exception:
            raise InvalidPayloadPOSTError()
        results = yield self._b_run(model, values)
        self.respond(results)
```

same in mod function

```
def mod(model):
    try:
        elastic_model = es.get(index = "index_name", doc_type='doc',id = model)
    except ApplicationError as e:
        logger.warning(e.message, e.code)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        logger.info('Either Tenant_id or Model_id NOT Found')
        raise InvalidTenantID()
```